# CiviMail Mail Opened report only shows one mailing in the filter

Tags: civimail

**CiviCRM 4.1.5**

I'm trying to customize the Mail Opened report to show a custom field. I try to select a Mailing Name from the filter but only one mailing name is listed. There are actually thousands of Mailings in the system

Comment: This works for me in version 4.5.5 at least. It may be bug in your version. Perhaps time to think about upgrading to a more recent release?

Comment: Yes. It works for later versions but we are not going to upgrade real soon.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is regarding a fairly old unsupported version (3+ years old?) of civicrm and is not relevant or reproducible in more recent versions